# problem in connecting SSH key to GitHub and cloning a repository

Tags: github, ssh-keys, cloning

I have a problem in cloning a repository by using SSH key. I create a SSH key exactly same as the procedure that is offered by GitHub  on the following address https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent
and I added the SSH key to my GitHub (setting/...) But when I want to clone a repository I keep getting this response:
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I also checked out the authentication and I think there is a problem there ..
MBP ~ % ssh -T git@github.com
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection refused

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you on your own personal computer? work computer? work network? Could it be that port 22 is blocked on whichever network you're currently on?

Comment: Yes, I am on my personal computer

Comment: I am a beginner in this case and this is my first time using SSH key and trying to use Github.